# AWS Linux 2 - Lets Encrypt Multi Domain

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have already successfully installed certbot and have a working digital certificate. I was wondering how do I go about adding domain names to the certificate or do I need to recreate the certificate again?

I don't want to mess up the existing certificate. I haven't tried running this code yet I want to verify the process before I continue. I tried searching this and Google and my results were kind of confusing.

> sudo certbot –apache -d mydomain.xyz -d mydomain2.xyz -d [www.mydomain.xyz](http://www.mydomain.xyz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL certificates cannot be modified once issued. They can be replaced with new certificates.

If you run the identical or modified **certbot** command, your existing certificate will not be modified or deleted. The certbot command will create a new certificate and store the certificate under a different name. Certbot stores certificates and additional files under the directory tree **/etc/letsencrypt**. You can archive/backup those files. Look at the **archive** and **live** folders.

Typically, your webserver will use symbolic links to point to the Let's Encrypt folder instead of copying the certificate to an Apache/Nginx folder.

Comment: So if I were to force renewal: `certbot -d domain.com,www.domain.com,domain2.com --force-renewal` would that update the certificate that is already in use?

Comment: @imvain2 Once issued, certificates cannot be modified. Your **--force-renewal** command would simply issue a new certificate.

Comment: what command would I need to run to implement the new certificate?

Comment: @imvain2 Certbot does that for you if certbot was correctly set up on your system to start with. Please do not use comments to ask new questions. Instead, either edit your existing question to clarify (one question per post) or create a new question. Your question about modifying an existing certificate with new domain names has been answered.